# Subscribption Form - Checkbox

Tags: php, forms, subscription

I have a subscribe form and I am having problem with the **checkbox** named "subscribe". When I register, checked the subscribe box and view my account, it isnt checked. You can find the checkbox before the submit button. Please help.

```
<?php
$errorMsg = "";
if (isset($_POST['username'])){

include_once "connect_to_mysql_members.php";
// Filter the posted variables
$username = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_POST['username']); // filter everything but numbers and letters
$firstname = ereg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['firstname']); // filter everything but spaces, numbers, and letters
$lastname = ereg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['lastname']); // filter everything but spaces, numbers, and letters
$address = ereg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['address']); // filter everything but spaces, numbers, and letters
$day = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_POST['day']); // filter everything but numbers
$month = ereg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['month']); // filter everything but spaces, numbers, and letters
$year = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_POST['year']); // filter everything but numbers
$accounttype = ereg_replace("[^a-z]", "", $_POST['accounttype']); // filter everything but lowercase letters
$email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
$email = strip_tags($email);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$password = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_POST['password']); // filter everything but numbers and letters
// Check to see if the user filled all fields with
// the "Required"(*) symbol next to them in the join form
// and print out to them what they have forgotten to put in
if((!$username) || (!$firstname) || (!$lastname) || (!$address) || (!$accounttype) || (!$email) || (!$password)){

    $errorMsg = "You did not submit the following required information!<br /><br />";
    if(!$username){
        $errorMsg .= "--- User Name";
    } else if(!$firstname){
        $errorMsg .= "--- First Name"; 
    } else if(!$lastname){ 
        $errorMsg .= "--- Last Name"; 
   } else if(!$address){ 
       $errorMsg .= "--- Address"; 
   } else if(!$accounttype){ 
       $errorMsg .= "--- Account Type"; 
   } else if(!$email){ 
       $errorMsg .= "--- Email Address"; 
   } else if(!$password){ 
       $errorMsg .= "--- Password"; 
   }
} else {
// Database duplicate Fields Check
$sql_username_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
$sql_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
$username_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_username_check);
$email_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_email_check); 
if ($username_check > 0){ 
    $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your User Name is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
} else if ($email_check > 0){ 
    $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your Email address is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
} else {
    // Add MD5 Hash to the password variable
   $hashedPass = md5($password); 
    // Add user info into the database table, claim your fields then values 
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username, firstname, lastname, address, gender, day, month, year, find, subscribe, accounttype, email, password, signupdate) 
    VALUES('$username','$firstname','$lastname','$address','$gender','$day','$month','$year','$find','$subscribe','$accounttype','$email','$hashedPass', now())") or die (mysql_error());
    // Get the inserted ID here to use in the activation email
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
    // Create directory(folder) to hold each user files(pics, MP3s, etc.) 
    mkdir("memberFiles/$id", 0755); 
    // Start assembly of Email Member the activation link
    $to = "$email";
    // Change this to your site admin email
    $from = "admin@webste.com";
    $subject = "Complete your registration";
    //Begin HTML Email Message where you need to change the activation URL inside
    $message = '<html>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    Hi ' . $username . ',
    <br /><br />
    Welcome to my website! You must complete this step to activate your account with us.
    <br /><br />
    Please click here to activate now &gt;&gt;
    <a href="http://website.com/activation.php?id=' . $id . '">
    ACTIVATE NOW</a>
    <br /><br />
    Your Login Data is as follows: 
    <br /><br />
    E-mail Address: ' . $email . ' <br />
    Password: ' . $password . ' 
    <br /><br /> 
    Thanks! 
    </body>
    </html>';
    // end of message
    $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $to = "$to";
    // Finally send the activation email to the member
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    // Then print a message to the browser for the joiner 
    print "<br /><br /><br /><h4>OK $firstname, one last step to verify your email identity:</h4><br />
    We just sent an Activation link to: $email<br /><br />
    <strong><font color=\"#990000\">Please check your email inbox in a moment</font></strong> to click on the Activation <br />
    Link inside the message. After email activation you can log in.";
    exit(); // Exit so the form and page does not display, just this success message
    } // Close else after database duplicate field value checks
  } // Close else after missing vars check
} //Close if $_POST
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>

<title>Website - Account Registration</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon.png" />
<link rel="icon" href="icon.png" type="image/x-icon" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" bottommargin="0">
<center>
<div id="pagewrap">
<?php include_once("header.php");?>

<div id="search_bar_bg"></div>

    <div id="pagetitle_register" style="margin-top:0px;"></div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1182">
    <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="230">
    <div id="product_category">
    <li><?php echo $toplink1; ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $toplink2; ?></li>

    </div>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="950">
    <div class="preview_inner">


<table width="950" >
  <form action="join_form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <?php echo "$errorMsg"; ?>
    <tr>
      <td width="131"><div align="left">User Name:</div></td>
      <td width="358"><input name="username" type="text" value="<?php echo "$username"; ?>" /></td>
      <td width="148">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="293">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><div align="left">First Name: </div></td>
  <td><input name="firstname" type="text" value="<?php echo "$firstname"; ?>" /></td>
  <td><div align="left">Last Name: </div></td>
  <td><input name="lastname" type="text" value="<?php echo "$lastname"; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Gender: </td>
  <td><select name="gender">
    <option value="<?php echo "$gender"; ?>"><?php echo "$gender"; ?></option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
  </select></td>
  <td><div align="left">Birthday: </div></td>
  <td><input id="day" type="tel" maxlength="2" placeholder="DD" width="10px" value="<?php echo "$day"; ?>"/> /
<input id="month" type="tel" maxlength="2" placeholder="MM" width="10px" value="<?php echo "$month"; ?>"/> /
<input id="year" type="tel" maxlength="4" placeholder="YYYY" width="10px" value="<?php echo "$year"; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div align="left">Address: </div></td>
  <td>
    <input name="address" type="text" width="100" value="<?php echo "$address"; ?>" />
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td><div align="left">Email: </div></td>
  <td><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo "$email"; ?>" /></td>
  <td><div align="left">Account Type: </div></td>
  <td><select name="accounttype">
    <option value="<?php echo "$accounttype"; ?>"><?php echo "$accounttype"; ?></option>
    <option value="a">Beauty Addict</option>
    <option value="b">Makeup Artist</option>
    <option value="c">Skin Expert</option>
  </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div align="left"> Password: </div></td>
  <td><input name="password" type="password" value="<?php echo "$password"; ?>" /> <br />
  <font size="-2" color="#006600">(letters or numbers only, no spaces and symbols)</font></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>How did you find us?</td>
  <td> <select name="find" id="find">
      <option>Store</option>
      <option>Magazines</option>
      <option>Newspapers</option>
      <option>Relatives and friends</option>
      <option>Online</option></select></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" id="subscribe" checked style="width:18px; height:18px;"> Subscribe to newsletter</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Form" /></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br /><?php include_once("footer.php");?>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sidenote [`ereg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/ereg_replace) This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged. And do not use MD5 for password storage nor `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Your checkbox does not have a named attribute, nor are you using a `$_POST` variable for it.

Comment: Sorry I am just learning. What do you use now instead of ereg_replace()? Thanks for letting me know about it.

What should be the $_POST for this checkbox? Will this code be ok for checkboxes? 
    $subscribe = ereg_replace("[^a-z]", "", $_POST['subscribe']);

Comment: You can get the information from the link I provided for you above.

Comment: No, the `ereg_replace` is not required for the checkbox. Only `$subscribe = $_POST['subscribe'];` is all that's required. Your input needs to resemble `<input type="checkbox" name="subscribe">`